# Prove $\lim \frac{3^n + 2^n}{5\cdot3^n + 7\cdot2^n} = \frac{1}{5}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove using limit definition.

$$\lim \frac{3^n + 2^n}{5\cdot 3^n + 7\cdot 2^n} = \frac{1}{5}
$$

My try:

$$\left| {\frac{3^n + 2^n}{5\cdot 3^n + 7\cdot 2^n} - \frac{1}{5}} \right| < \varepsilon
$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \left| \frac{3^n + 2^n - 5\cdot 3^n - 7\cdot 2^n}{5(5\cdot3^n + 7\cdot2^n)} \right| < \varepsilon \
$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{4\cdot 3^n + 5\cdot 2^n}{5(5\cdot 3^n + 7\cdot 2^n)} < \varepsilon 
$$

I can increase numerator next and simplify like this:

$$\frac{4\cdot 3^n + 5\cdot 2^n}{5(5\cdot 3^n + 7\cdot 2^n)} < \,\frac{5\cdot 3^n + 7\cdot 2^n}{5\cdot (5\cdot 3^n + 7\cdot 2^n)} = \frac{1}{5}
$$

But in this case I'm loosing the $n$ in the dominator.

Comment: You have $|2^n - 7\cdot 2^n|$ and you changed it to $5\cdot 2^n$, but it should be $6\cdot 2^n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note that $\frac{3^n + 2^n}{5 \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n} - \frac{1}{5} = \frac{5 \cdot 3^n + 5 \cdot 2^n}{5 (5 \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n) } - \frac{5 \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n}{5 (5 \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n) } = \frac{ - 2^{n+1} }{5( 5 \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n) }$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

> $$
> \frac{ 3^n + 2^n }{ 5 \times 3^n + 7 \times 2^n } 
> = \frac{ \color{red}{1} + (2/3)^n }{ \color{red}{5} + 7 \times (2/3)^n }
> $$

Comment: Solid HINT!! +1

Comment: @Dr.MV, Thanks!

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Answer (score 0):

If you know `equivalents` in Asymptotic analysis, that is easy:
$\;3^n+2^n\sim3^n$, $\sim5\times3^n$, hence
$$\frac{3^n+2^n}{5\times3^n+7\times2^n}\sim\frac{3^n}{5\times3^n}=\frac15.$$

Comment: But this is not using the definition of limit of a sequence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If the sequence is equivalent to a *number* $\ell$, it exactly means it converges to $\ell$.

Comment: But that's still not using the definition of "limit". It's using a _theorem_ rather than using the _definition_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh! I see the problem, but it's the same for the other answer if you mean an ε-δ definition. There *is* a limit hidden in the notion of equivalent functions, since it means their quotient has limit $1$.

Comment: The other answer is only a first step, but seems to lend itself to use in an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof. ${}\qquad{}$